# QEMU not starting in desktop window as of 20.04

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

Greatings!
After upgrading from 18.xx QEMU starts not as expected.

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-60-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

The launch command is unchanged:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 6G -smp cores=3 -cpu (...) ***-vga virtio*** -usb (...)
```

Upon launching the command the VM starts correctly but output is sent to VNC 127.0.0.1:5900 and thus requires Remmina or similar.

The expected behaviour would be the VM starting in a desktop manager window. I've read thru the QEMU documentation to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: the `-vga ` which you left in your example is about what you present to the guest. The argument how it is on the host would be `-display` and here I'd expect that this in earlier releases was `-display sdl` but now should be `-display gtk`.

Comment: Will try as soon as workstation available. Txs